# How to create a new folder in root of SdCard on Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-external-storage, android-storage

I want to create a new folder in Root or main page of SdCard. I have use this method to get SdCard location:

```
File("/storage/sdcard1", "New folder")
```

But this method didn't work on some devices. I need an method that work on all devices and get SdCard location.

I have also tried :

```
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"New folder")
```

But this method target device storage. But I want SdCard.

Comment: see https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html

Comment: Creating any files or folders requires runtime permission from "DocumentTree"

Comment: There is no requirement for a device to have [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), and you do not have write access to arbitrary locations on removable storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare But some application can do this for example es file explorer app can read and write SdCard.

Comment: @UmangBurman But my code works on some devices without requires runtime permission from "DocumentTree".

Comment: @MIbrarRaza ES File Explorer also requests permission at the start. It depends on the API level.

Comment: @UmangBurman But I have tried my code on android jelly bean and kitkat so I no need permission at start.

Comment: Did you try it in Lollipop? @MIbrarRaza

Comment: @UmangBurman no I haven't try this on lollipop. I need code that works on all devices and android versions.

Comment: You need to check the version, Below answer is legit.. In Android there is no one type of code for all.. it depends on you on how you want it to be.. Put a check and proceed

Answer (score 0):

When you want to create the folder run the following line of code:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), 42);
```

Choose your SD card from the dialog that appears. The following method will get called after you have closed the dialog and inside there you can create your directory.

```
@Override 
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       switch (requestCode) {
                            // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
          case 42:

             if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)  return;

             if(data != null) { 
             Uri treeUri = data.getData();
             grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);                               
             getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
             DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri );
             DocumentFile myDirectory =  pickedDir.createDirectory("MyDirectory");
            }
          break;

       default:  break;
    }
}
```

PS1: 42 is a random number i use. Choose any unique positive integer instead of 42 if you like. Better even make it a constant.

PS2: In `onActivityResult` you can save the `treeUri` value to some variable,database,etc so everytime you need to create more folders or files in the SD root directory, you can have it readily available.

Comment: There was an error occurs says "Cannot resolve symbol 'data' " What should i do?

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it is clear now. PS: It would be good practice to check if there is an SD card present before going through all that.

Comment: Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE requires lollipop version of android but as I have write in question I need code that works on all versions of android and all devices.

Comment: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.L){
do it my way
}else{
Do it as you would if it was not an SD but regular storage. Use file instead of DocumentFile
}`

Comment: I need full code that works on all devices and and all API levels please help.